# how to properly use any function in middleware in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am able to use `checkAuth` function when i use my method like this

```
router.get('/login',checkAuth, function(){

})
```

but how to use `checkAuth` function when my method is like this

routes file

```
router.get('/login',controller.login);
```

controller file

```
export function newPassword(req,res) {

 }
```

please help me.

thanx in advance.

Comment: you can use like this  `app.use(checkAuth)`

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: Maybe `router.get('/login',checkAuth, controller.login);` ???!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkAuth is a middleware, according to this, it has the following prototype :

```
function(req, res, next)
```

You can use it in your route as a middleware :

```
router.get('/login',checkAuth, controller.login);
```

Or you can use it in your controller.login function by overriding the next :

```
var checkAuth = require("./mymodule.js");

exports.login = function(req, res){

   checkAuth(req, res, function(){

       // callback function overriding next()

       // do stg here
   });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this `app.use(checkAuth);`. app is an express object, It'll check for all the routes, You don't have to write middleware for all routes.